# Need to be clarify recursion method in find min element in the array

Tags: java, recursion

I know that someone already asked this question before, but I still don't quite understand what happen behind the scene. The question is find the minimum element in the array.

Suppose I have  int [] a = { 3, 2, 5, 7};

The way I am understanding is that:

mid = (0 + 3)/ 2 = 1 
    then min1 = min(a, 0, mid 'which is 1')
         mid = (0 + 1)/ 2 = 0
             then min1 = min(a, 0, mid 'which is 0')
 so now the condition is met, then it return a[0] which is 3.

That's what I'm thinking right now. And also I don't see any code that is finding the minimum element in each half of array.

Please explain to me clearly.

Thank you

```
private static int min(int[] array, int start, int end){
                        // a           0           3

    if(start == end){
        return array[start];
    }

    int mid = (start+end)/2;
    int min1 = min(array, start, mid);
    int min2 = min(array, mid + 1, end);

    return (min1 < min2) ? min1: min2;
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Are you wondering why the method returns 3 instead of 2? Remember that it returns 3 only when you consider only the first element, and otherwise it returns the smaller of the mins of the first and the seconds half.

Comment: Hello tobias_k, if it returns 3, where is the code to check the minimum element from min 1.

Comment: Its a divide and conquer: it partitions the array in to two parts and looks for the minimun in each of the parts(again by partioning) and compares those found minimums.  
( If you agree with me, that the naive/iterative  aproach is easier to grasp: i add the naive/iterative aproach should also be faster, more stable and less errorprone.)

Comment: Hi Kai, ya I know that using iterator is much easier, but my professor wants us to use recursion :(.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm